# Laravel + javascript application: delay in ability to re-edit data entries

Tags: javascript, sql, laravel

We are currently facing an issue with data re-edits in an application based on laravel 6 and javascript for front.

The application allows a logged in user to edit data entries previously added from him/her or other users. The workflow goes like this: a user edits a data-entry and saves it ( there are two steps: getting in edit mode and exiting by saving the edited data). While a user is in edit mode, the data-entry is "locked" and no other user can edit it while it is locked. After save, the data-entry "opens" again. The locking mechanism works on the level of the database: there is a field that is null while no one edits a data-entry and it gets the user id as a value when someone gets in edit mode. After saving the new changes, the field becomes empty again.

For some reason it seems that some times the locking mechanism takes to much time to unlock, although the user has pressed save and has exited the edit mode. This happens only on the client side where multiple users use the application. When we use the same server and application, from our side, nothing similar happens; the locking and unlocking works correctly.

Are there any possible usual causes that could create this issue? Could this perhaps be due to multiple queries from the client network and something there takes more time than it should, but when we do it from our side, we don't face such an issue?

Is there some plugin we could use to check what may cause this issue, perhaps the queries and if they hang or get in some sort of execution line that takes way to much time to finish?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use the built in logger? Log the moment the field you're using the lock the row changes value and the moment a user tries to edit the data-entry.

```php
// lock data-entry and show form
public function edit(Request $request, DataEntry $dt)
{
    // log attempt and lock status
    Log::debug(Auth::user()->email . ' is trying to edit data-entry ' . $dt->id . ' (lock status: ' . $dt->lockField . ')');
    // check if user should be allowed to edit
    if ($dt->lockField != null) { /* deny attempt */ }    
    // update lock status
    $dt->fill(['lockfield' => ...])->save();
    // return edit view
}

// update data-entry and unlock it.
public function update(Request $request, DataEntry $dt)
{
    // update dt fields
    $dt->fill(...)->save();
    // update lock status
    $dt->fill(['lockfield' => null])->save();
    // log lock status
    Log::debug('Data-entry '. $dt->id . ' was just updated. Lock status: ' . $dt->lockField);
    // return
}
```

This would show in your logs with timestamps. You could make sure there is a delay or if the users are being overly eager.

If you see something like

```
[YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00] Data-entry 1 was updated just updated. Lock status: null
[YYYY-MM-DD 00:01:00] user@email is trying to edit data-entry 1 (lock status: not null)
```

Then you have a problem.

Maybe it could be user error. Are you sure they are not closing the form instead of submitting it?

If you think there is a delay in your queries, you could also try logging them through the DB facade.

```
// Inside AppServiceProvider@boot method. Or any other ServiceProvider really
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    Log::debug([
        'sql' => $query->sql,
        'bindings' => $query->bindings,
        'time' => $query->time,
    ]);
});
```

If you the logging part to be taken care of by a package, you *could* use something like laravel-auditable but I think it's not warranted for this case.

---

Another thing I just thought of: Are you using a cached value to return the data-entry when an user wants to edit it? If you are, make sure you are clearing the key when the lockField is updated.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer - I will check everything mentioned in the post. Since not all parts of the code are developed by one person, could I ask something for the last part of your answer: is the cache system you refer related to laravel ( and is there something code specific? ) or are you referring in general to javascript and the server also? Thank you again.

Comment: I'm referring to Laravel's cache. If the data-entry is retrieved for example, using `cache()->remember(key, ttl, callback)` or `Cache::remember(key, ttl, callback)` or some other cache function, its values might not always be up to date and you'd need to manually delete `key` from the cache after every `lockField` modification.